# Is it possible to simulate a soccer game using Humanoids in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

*Hello Everyone!!*

Is it possible to simulate a soccer game using Humanoids in Gazebo?

*A lot of thanks!!*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4516/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-soccer-game-using-humanoids-in-gazebo?/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-10-02**:
@nkoenig
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's possible, but simulation would be mighty slow (depending on the complexity of the humanoid robots)

Defining the soccer field would be easier. Just create a flat plane with a green texture and the appropriate lines. The goals can be modeled using cylinders and boxes.

Next, you'd have to create a humanoid model, or use Atlas. Controlling the humanoid robot is also no small feat, but definitely do-able.

Then you'd have to model the dynamics of the soccer ball. You could potentially use a Bullet soft-body.

A world-plugin could be used to keep score, and track the ball for out-of-bounds. And you could also get fancy by monitoring collisions between robots for fouls.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1